# example for algebraic but not finite dimensional vector space

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

there is a theorem on Galois theory that

if **F** is a finite dimensional extension field of **K** (say **[F:K]=n**) then **F** is algebraic over **K**

I'm thinking about the converse of this statement. is the converse false? can anyone give me an example that contradict the converse

Comment: the set of all algebraic numbers over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 8):

An extension $K/F$ is said to be algebraic if all of the elements of $K$ are algebraic over $F$, i.e. the solutions of polynomials in $F[X]$. Let's take the field extension $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\ldots, \sqrt{n},\ldots)$. Every element we adjoin is algebraic. Indeed, $\sqrt{n}$ satisfies $x^2-n=0$. So, this extension is algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$, but it certainly isn't finite.

Comment: is {$\sqrt 1$, $\sqrt 2$, ..., $\sqrt n$,...| where **n** is not a perfect square } a basis for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, ...)$

Comment: Yes, you can prove that. I probably should have said $\sqrt{n}$ for $n$ not a perfect square, but writing it changes nothing, since when $n$ is a perfect square $\sqrt{n}$ is in $\mathbf{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

**First example**: Let $K:=\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rationals;
and let $K:=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ be it's algebraic clousure.
Then $F/K$ is algebraic but it is not finite dimentional.

---

---

**Second example**: Let $K:=\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rationals;
and let's consider an infinite set of algebraic elements $A$; such that any finite set of $A$ is algebraicly independent. Then let $K:=\mathbb{Q}(A)$.

If you let 
$A= \bigg{\{} \sqrt{p} \ : \ p \ \text{is a prime number} \ \bigg{\}}$;
and let $K:=\mathbb{Q}(A)$; then you will get exactly the [answer of Antonios-Alexandros Robotis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525192/example-for-algebraic-but-not-finite-dimensional-vector-space/2525197#2525197).
Note that $\mathbb{Q}(A)=\mathbb{Q}(A')$; where 
$A'= \bigg{\{} \sqrt{n} \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \bigg{\}}$.

Also if you let
$A=$ set of all algebraic elements;
then you will get the first example.

---

Now you can construct another examples;

- $A= \bigg{\{} \sqrt[3]{p} \ : \ p \ \text{is a prime number} \ \bigg{\}}$;
- $A= \bigg{\{} \sqrt[2p+1]{p} \ : \ p \ \text{is a prime number} \ \bigg{\}}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb F$ is an *algebraic* extension of a field $\Bbb K$ if every element $\phi \in \Bbb F$ satisfies some polynomial $k(x) \in \Bbb K[x]$; $k(\phi) = 0$. As such, we need not have $[\Bbb F: \Bbb K] < \infty$, since different elements of $\Bbb F$ may satisfy polynomials over $\Bbb K$ of different degrees.  The most ready example is probably the field of algebraic numbers over $\Bbb Q$, which contains elements satisfying polynomials $p(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$ of every degree.  See [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_extension) for more.